# Vector Space span/basis {1,$sin^2(x),cos^2(x)$}

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

How can I determine whether or not it
 (a) spans the vector space provided
 (b) is a basis for this vector space?

Answer (score 2):

$a)$ and $b)$ are false. For example, if $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $$\sin x=a+b\sin²x+c\cos²x,$$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $$1=a+b$$ and when $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ $$-1=a+b.$$ Therefore $1=a+b=-1$, a contradiction. Thus a=b=0. Also, when $x=0$ we have $$0=c\cos²0=c,$$ other contradiction. We concludes that $\{1,\sin²x,\cos²x\}$ does not spans $C(-\infty,\infty)$.

Note that $\{1,\sin^{2}x,\cos^{2}x\}$ is linearly dependent, because $$1-\sin^{2}x-\cos²{x}=0.$$

Comment: 1) The first proof can be shortened a bit: you already get the contradiction $1 = a+b = -1$ after the first two lines.  2) L.D. is not a standard abbreviation: I assume you mean "linearly dependent", but it is was unclear to me so it probably is unclear to some other readers.

Comment: @ErickWong L.D. mean linearly dependent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer in a different way by working on equivalent "span" spaces:

$$span\{1,\cos^2x,\sin^2x\}=span\{1,\cos^2x\}= span\{1,\cos 2x\}$$

The first equality by relationship $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$, the second 
by the (classical) formulas $\cos^2x=\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2a)) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sin^2x=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2a))$.

Thus, the considered "span" is the 2 dimensional vector space of functions $f$ defined

- either by $f(x)=a+b\cos^2x$
- or by $f(x)=\alpha+\beta \cos(2x)$

which, in both cases, is far from representing the (infinite dimensional) vector space of real-valued continuous functions on $(-\infty,+\infty)$.